# Text appended to path does not show

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, calendar

I have a calendar heat map and I need to add underneath each path grouping the month a label showing the month name.

There a `path` element per each month, having the first date of that month as `data`, so I'm using

```
  monthGroup.append("text")
            .attr("class", "heatMonthLabel")
            .text(function (d) { return d.toString().substr(4, 3);})
            .style("text-anchor","middle");
```

In the element inspector  of the browser it does show up but no trace of them in the page. This is a live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/MaT5R/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the `text` element to the `g`, not the `path` element -- SVG will not render text appended to `path` elements.

Modified jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MaT5R/2/). I've also added code to set the position of the `text` elements.